# Problem with alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, indentation

I currently have

```
\textbf{Theorem 4: } $\mathrm{E}[XY]=\mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y]$

\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{Proof: }     \mathrm{E}[XY]&=\sum_j\sum_i (x_i y_j)\mathrm{P}     
 (x_i)\mathrm{P}(y_j)=\sum_j\sum_i x_i\mathrm{P}(x_i) \ y_j\mathrm{P}(y_j) \\
 &=\sum_j y_j\mathrm{P}(y_j)\ \sum_i x_i\mathrm{P}(x_i)=\mathrm{E}     
 [X]\mathrm{E}[Y]
\end{flalign*}
```

which produces the theorem and proof in the image[image: current formatting]

The proof is indented and not in-line with the theorem, and all of this is not in-line with the rest of the document (shown by the black line).

My question is how would I go about creating what is shown in the image below:
[image]

I have tried including everything within `\begin{flalign*}` and using `&` to align everything but this ended with the proof being indented further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd place the entire construction inside an `flalign` rather than break them apart:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \textbf{Theorem 4: } \mathrm{E}[XY] &= \mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y] & \\
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\bfseries Proof: }\hphantom{\textbf{Theorem 4: }}
    \mathrm{E}[XY] &= \sum_j\sum_i (x_i y_j)\mathrm{P}
    (x_i)\mathrm{P}(y_j)=\sum_j\sum_i x_i\mathrm{P}(x_i) \ y_j\mathrm{P}(y_j) \\
                                      &= \sum_j y_j\mathrm{P}(y_j)\ \sum_i x_i\mathrm{P}(x_i) = \mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y]
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

`Proof` is placed inside a zero-width box to achieve the displayed alignment with `Theorem 4` (using `\hphantom`).

Note the use of an additional alignment operator `&` in the first line. This is done in order to achieve the flush-left display.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist to use unusual way to wrote theorems, proofs, lemmas ... than with `flaling` you can obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% for showing equations only
\PreviewEnvironment{flalign*}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{Theorem 4:} &&  
    \mathrm{E}[XY] & = \mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y]                               \\
\textbf{Proof:} &&  
    \mathrm{E}[XY] & = \sum_j\sum_i (x_i y_j)\mathrm{P} (x_i)\mathrm{P}(y_j) 
                        = \sum_j\sum_i x_i\mathrm{P}(x_i) \ y_j\mathrm{P}(y_j)  \\
                &&&= \sum_j y_j\mathrm{P}(y_j)\ \sum_i x_i\mathrm{P}(x_i)=\mathrm{E}
 [X]\mathrm{E}[Y]
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More proper way is to use one of packages dedicated for writing this. Of course, with them your particular wish for formatting the equations in them is difficult to achieve.

Comment: the spacing after the `=` sign in the theorem line is incorrect.  if the `=` *follows* an `&` the spacing will be good; that is how the alignment environments are designed to work; if the `=` is placed before `&`, then input it as `{} = &`.

Comment: You have right. I will correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

**Please ignore this answer if you want a pure LaTeX solution**

---

**[Dangerous bend sign]** Since this site mainly concentrates on LaTeX and the AMS math environments, I hesitate to offer a plain TeX solution, but in this case you can get the flexibility you want with a fairly simple alignment.  It's all explained in Chapter 22 of the TeXBook.

[image]

```
\noindent
Plain \TeX\ version:
\def\E[#1]{\mathop{\rm E}[\vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}]}
\def\P{\mathop{\rm P}}
%
\par\bigskip\noindent
\vbox{\openup6pt\halign{\bf #\hfil\quad &\hfil$\displaystyle #$&&$\displaystyle {}#$\hfil\cr
Theorem 4: & \E[XY] &=\E[X]\E[Y]\cr
\noalign{\medskip}
Proof:     & \E[XY] &=\sum_j \sum_i (x_i y_j)\P(x_i)\P(y_j) &=\sum_j\sum_i x_i\P(x_i) \, y_j\P(y_j) \cr
           &        &=\sum_j y_j\P(y_j)\,\sum_i x_i\P(x_i)  &=\E[X]\E[Y]\cr
}}
\bigskip

\noindent
In particular, any associated supporting element necessitates that urgent
consideration be applied to possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.
Conversely, any associated supporting element recognizes other systems' importance
and the necessity for possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.

\medskip\noindent
Or you might prefer a slightly tighter version without {\tt displaystyle}.
\par\bigskip\noindent
\vbox{\openup6pt\halign{\bf #\hfil\quad &\hfil$#$&&${}#$\hfil\cr
Theorem 4: & \E[XY] &=\E[X]\E[Y]\cr
Proof:     & \E[XY] &=\sum_j \sum_i (x_i y_j)\P(x_i)\P(y_j) &=\sum_j\sum_i x_i\P(x_i) \, y_j\P(y_j) \cr
           &        &=\sum_j y_j\P(y_j)\,\sum_i x_i\P(x_i)  &=\E[X]\E[Y]\cr
}}
\bigskip

\bye
```

Thanks to backward compatibility, you can of course use parts of this solution inside most LaTeX documents, but you will need to know what you are doing.

You might notice that the square brackets and the upper case letters are not vertically centred in Computer Modern.  I find that visually irritating, so I've included a little macro that centers them up.

```
\def\E[#1]{\mathop{\rm E}[\vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}]}
```

This macro takes advantage of the full parsing flexibility of plain TeX but is clearly entirely non-standard for LaTeX which keeps brackets for optional arguments.  Here the brackets are used as argument delimiters in the macro definition.  The replacement part of the macro puts them back in around a properly centred argument. Defining `E` to be a `mathop` makes it also properly aligned to the brackets.